# Pass data between Activities in onClickListener

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

I want to get a string and send it via the `onClickListener` method to other activity, I already have the code in another activity where it will be catched, I get it to work by doing this:
Example: `String Culo = lblMensaje.getText().toString;`

This way I could get the text and send it to another activity, but its not as efficent as sending the original string.. Would it be posible to send it?

```
final String sexos[] =
                new String[] {"00311712 Biología I","Mar-Jue 7:00am Prof.Briceño","Elem3","Elem4","Elem5"};

      final String[] datos =
                 new String[]{"0031711 Lab Biologia","Lun-Mar 9:30am prof. Marcarian","Elem3","Elem4","Elem5"};



        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.pipe);

            final TextView lblMensaje = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.LblMensaje);
            final Spinner cmbOpciones = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.CmbOpciones);

            final String[] datos =
                    new String[]{"0031711 Lab Biologia","Lun-Mar 9:30am prof. Marcarian","Elem3","Elem4","Elem5"};


            ArrayAdapter<String> pipe =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, datos);


            pipe.setDropDownViewResource(
              R.layout.multiline_spinner_dropdown_item);



            cmbOpciones.setAdapter(pipe);

            cmbOpciones.setOnItemSelectedListener(
             new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                        android.view.View v, int position, long id) {
                            lblMensaje.setText("Seleccionado: " + datos[position]);



                    }

                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                        lblMensaje.setText("");
                    }

            });


            final TextView lblMensaje1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.LblMensaje1);
            final Spinner cmbOpciones1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.CmbOpciones1);

            final String sexos[] =
               new String[] {"00311712 Biología I","Mar-Jue 7:00am Prof.Briceño","Elem3","Elem4","Elem5"};

         ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador1 =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sexos);



        adaptador1.setDropDownViewResource(
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);



        cmbOpciones1.setAdapter(adaptador1);

        cmbOpciones1.setOnItemSelectedListener(
         new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                    android.view.View v, final int position, long id) {          
                        lblMensaje1.setText(sexos[position]);




                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    lblMensaje1.setText("");
                }


        });
        Button BotonPasar1;
        BotonPasar1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.VB1);
         BotonPasar1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

         public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            String Culo;

       Culo = datos[position];
            String Culoq;
            Culoq = sexos[position];



            SharedPreferences mypreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mypreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("Culo",Culo);
            editor.commit();



               SharedPreferences mypreferences1 = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
              SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = mypreferences1.edit();
            editor1.putString("Culoq", Culoq);
            editor1.commit();

                  String Culo1 = String.valueOf(Culoq + 1);

            SharedPreferences mypreferences2 = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = mypreferences2.edit();
            editor2.putString("Culo1",Culo1);
            editor2.commit();

         }

        });
         Button BotonPasar2;
         BotonPasar2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.VB2);
          BotonPasar2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

          public void onClick(View v) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           Intent pasarahorario = new Intent("com.reversiblelabs.unisvenecas.udobeta.HORARIO");                          
          startActivity(pasarahorario);

          }

         });


        }

    }
```

Comment: getText already returns a string theres no reason to call toString on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may helps you

like SharedPreferences
in your First ActivityA

```
           Intent myintent= new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            SharedPreferences spref = this.getSharedPreferences("mynotifyid", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor spreedit = spref.edit();
            spreedit.putString("Name1", str1.toString());              
            spreedit.commit();
            startActivity(myintent);
```

in your Second ActivityB

```
        SharedPreferences spref = context.getSharedPreferences("mynotifyid", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
        String str1 = spref.getString("Name1","");
```

for your object saving purpose use SharedPreferences

Answer (score 0):

By using intents you can just use the putextra method and catch it in the other class?

in the onClick method where you say:

```
Intent pasarahorario = new Intent("com.reversiblelabs.unisvenecas.udobeta.HORARIO");                          
startActivity(pasarahorario);
```

just add

```
pasarahorario.putExtra("title", lblMensaje.getText().toString);
```

and in the other activity you call:

```
String text = getIntent().getExtras().get("title").toString();
```

Comment: Can't comment below so i comment here instead:

You need to specifiy what you want to know because right now it seems like you just want to send information between activities.

Comment: i want to send datos[position] directly to another activity by using shared preferences

Comment: oh, in that case:

Main activity: 
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("datos", lblMensaje.getText().toString); //Or another way to get the string (maybe just datos[position])
editor.commit();

Then in activity 2 you call
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
String Datos[] = settings.getString("datos", "");

Also remember to use the same name for PREFS_NAME

 public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile"; for instance

Comment: i understand all you have done there, but the real problem here is that, when you declare String Culo = datos[position] gives me an error, with the position part, onClick method is not letting me use the Position..

Comment: Isn't that because you don't have a position variable in the onClick Method? I don't think you need the position part at all if you just want to send the entire string array? Which part of the array do you want to return? try testing it by sending saying: String culo = datos[0]; and see what you get :)

Comment: sorry if I dont make myself clear I am not a native speaker, What i am trying to do is to send a specific array depending of its position in the string